# Jquery validation message without using plug in

Tags: jquery

```
    <form action="" method="post" class="a">
        Name : <input type="text" class="text" name="name" id="name" /> <br/>
<span id="sName"></span>
        Address : <input type="text" class="text" name="address" id="address" /> 
<span id="sAddress"></span>
<br/>
        email : <input type="text" class="text" name="email" id="email" /> <br/>
<span id="sEmail"></span>
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
```

How to display error messages in span tag on submit click

Comment: Have you tried something yourself?

Comment: This has been asked more times that I can count. Try a simple search before asking http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+form+validation+no+plugin

Answer (score -1):

This is one way to do it without using plugins (which are better then trying to do it yourself because they have a lot more options)
Working code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var address = $("#address").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();

    $("#submit").click(function () {

        if (name == "") $("#sName").show();

        if (name == "") $("#sAddress").show();

        if (name == "") $("#sEmail").show();

    });


});
```

```css
#sName, #sAddress, #sEmail {
    display: none;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class="a">Name :
    <input type="text" class="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <br/>
<span id="sName">Please enter your name</span>

    <br>Address :
    <input type="text" class="text" name="address" id="address" />
    <br>
<span id="sAddress">Please enter your address</span>

    <br>email :
    <input type="text" class="text" name="email" id="email" />
    <br/>
<span id="sEmail">Please enter your e-mail</span>

    <br>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```